# Is it possible to configure Selenium 2 Grid to log a client ipaddress

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a small grid running and a couple of teams in my organization are using it. I'd like to  know from which teams grid requests are originating from. I can't find any client info in the current grid logs.

Can i configure log4j? Or do i need to use grid 2 plugin architecture to create a logging plugin?

I'm using selenium 2.37

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess for solution is below. Excuse me if that does not seems to be feasible.

1. Get the Selenium source from the GIT and edit the file of the grid
   which gets the request.
2. Try if you can get the IP adddress of the
   node in the code.
3. If that works and okay for you, you can make your modified code as a JAR
   and use it for distribution to your team.

Source: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/

Grid for Java: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used log4j, so I'm not sure about that.
However, we have created a custom logger that we use with vstest.
In the logger, we grab the computer name and persist it to the database along with the results.
This has worked very well for us.